# Having trouble with the math for a loan calculator program

Tags: java

This is a loan calculator program. I'm having trouble with the math. Everything else seems to be correct except for the value of the beginning balance after 2 months. Notice that the beginning balance of the 3rd month is different from the ending balance of the 2nd month. Same thing for the succeeding months. I've been trying to fix it but everything didn't work out. I need them to be the same so the ending balance of the last month will be 0.

### This is a sample output of the program:

```
Personal Loan Payment Calculator

Enter a loan amount: 1000
Enter the loan term (months): 6
Enter the interest rate (% per year): 9             

                Loan Payment and Amortization Table

   Months  Beginning    Monthly  Principal   Interest     Ending    
             Balance     Payment     Paid        Paid     Balance

        1    1000.00     171.07     163.57       7.50     836.43
        2     836.43     171.07     164.80       6.27     671.64
        3     670.41     171.07     166.04       5.03     504.37
        4     501.88     171.07     167.30       3.76     334.57
        5     330.78     171.07     168.59       2.48     162.19
        6     157.06     171.07     169.89       1.18     -12.83



Summary:
========
Loan Amount:           $1,000.00
Monthly Payment:       $171.07
Number of Payments:    6
Total Interest Paid:   $24.00
Annual Interest Rate:  9.00%
```

### This is the program:

```
 public class LoanCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Personal Loan Payment Calculator"); // print the name of the program
            System.out.println("================================");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); // define a Scanner object attached to a keyboard
            String badInput; // assign non-integer or non-double inputs to badInput

            System.out.print("Enter a loan amount: "); // prompt the user to enter loan amount
            while ( ! keyboard.hasNextDouble()) // is the first input value a double?
            {
                badInput = keyboard.next();
                System.out.println("Error: expected a Double, encountered: " + badInput);
                System.out.println("Please enter a loan amount in Double: ");
            }
            double loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble(); // assign the first input to loanAmount

            System.out.print("Enter the loan term (months): "); // prompt the user to enter number of months
            while ( ! keyboard.hasNextInt()) // is the second input value an int?
            {
                badInput = keyboard.next();
                System.out.println("Error: expected an Integer, encountered: " + badInput);
                System.out.println("Please enter a loan term in Integer: ");
            }
            int loanTerm = keyboard.nextInt(); // assign the second input to loanTerm

            System.out.print("Enter the interest rate (% per year): "); // prompt the user to enter the interest rate
            while ( ! keyboard.hasNextDouble()) // is the first input value a double?
            {
                badInput = keyboard.next();
                System.out.println("Error: expected an integer, encountered: " + badInput);
                System.out.println("Please enter a loan amount in Double: ");
            }
            double interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble(); // assign the third input to interestRate

            System.out.println(); // skip a line

            System.out.println("             Loan Payment and Amortization Table");
            System.out.printf("%s", "=============================================================");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%5s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", "Months" ,"Beginning", "Monhtly", "Principal", "Interest", "Ending");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf(" %5s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", "#","Balance", "Payment", "Paid", "Paid", "Balance");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s ", "=============================================================");
            System.out.println();

            double monthlyRate = (interestRate / 100.0) / 12.0;
            double monthlyPayment = (monthlyRate * loanAmount) / ( 1 - (Math.pow( 1 + monthlyRate, - loanTerm)));
            double beginningBalance = loanAmount;
            double interestPaid = beginningBalance * monthlyRate;
            double principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;

            int total_interest_paid = 0;
            for (int monthCount = 0 ; monthCount < loanTerm ; ++monthCount)
            {
              int months = 1 + monthCount;
              beginningBalance = loanAmount - principalPaid * monthCount; 
              interestPaid = beginningBalance * monthlyRate;
              principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;            
              double endingBalance = beginningBalance - principalPaid;
              System.out.printf(" %5d %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f\n", months, beginningBalance, monthlyPayment, principalPaid, interestPaid, endingBalance);

              total_interest_paid += interestPaid;
            }


            System.out.printf("%s ", "=============================================================");
            System.out.println();

            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            DecimalFormat percentFormat = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");

            System.out.println("\nSummary:");
            System.out.println("========");
            System.out.println("Loan Amount:           " + currency.format(loanAmount));
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment:       " + currency.format(monthlyPayment));
            System.out.println("Number of Payments:    " + loanTerm);
            System.out.println("Total Interest Paid:   " + currency.format(total_interest_paid));
            System.out.println("Annual Interest Rate:  " + percentFormat.format(interestRate) + "%");       
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very simple:

```
beginningBalance = loanAmount - principalPaid * monthCount;
```

Remember that "principalPaid" increases every month. The total principal paid is not the last principalPaid * mouthCount but the sum of the principal paid in all months.

You could create a running total for principalPaid like you did for interest paid.
But it would be much easier to do beginningBalance = previous month endingBalance.